# MySQL Trigger to update NULL fields with 0 as long as previous record's length

Tags: mysql, sql, string, triggers

My table contains 4 fields "number1,number2,number3,number4", so filling those fields after some calculations and most of the tables contains between 1.000 and 700.000 records.

Mostly table data looks like this;

```
number1  number2  number3  number4
1234567  1234567  1234567  1234567
```

But sometimes any field's value is not calculating and looks like this;

```
number1  number2  number3  number4
0        0        1234567  1234567
```

I'm exporting table's data to csv file so the laboratory's machine's software can import the data, my problem starts here, in the csv file data must be seperated by comma and all fields should be on same length, with php loop i'm able to sort NULL fields and update those fields as 0 as long as previous record's length, for example;

```
number1  number2  number3  number4
1234567  1234567  1234567  1234567
0000000  0000000  1234567  0000000
```

as you know when data is big it takes so much time.

I was wondering is it possible to create an trigger to do it, when row created and if some of the fields are NULL then it should update NULL fields with 0 as long as previous record's length.

PS: I've used 7 character long numbers in the examples but numbers are dynamic, sometimes columns on each row 16 characters long, sometimes 70 characters long, so almost all rows has different length, that's why i'm trying to set length of NULL cell's column according to previous record's length.

Comment: 'according to previous record's length.' - I don't get .. do you mean pad to the longest column in a row or the longest same column in previous rows? And I guess none of the columns are numeric datatypes?

Comment: @P.Salmon just imagine table's first row is like this : 12345678910,12345678910,12345678910 and the second row like this : NULL,12345678910,NULL,12345678910 now on the previous record all cells are 11 character long, now i need to set NULL cells like 00000000000,00000000000 (with 11 zeros), but the problem is not all rows has the same length on the table for example 1st row's cells are 11 character long, 2nd row's cells are 5 character long

Comment: What should happen if the first row is 7 the second row 10 and the 3rd row 5. should 1 become 10 or 2 become 7 etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want all columns to be the same as the longest column value then you cannot use a trigger since a trigger cannot action the table which fired it. You could use an sp to find the max column length and dynamic sql to pad for example

```
drop table if exists t;
create table t
(n1 char(10),n2 char(10));

insert into t values
(123,456),
(1111,222);

drop procedure if exists p;
delimiter $$
create procedure p()
begin

    select   l into @vmaxlen
    from
    (
    select   max(length(n1)) l from t
    union
    select   max(length(n2)) from t
    ) s
    order by l desc limit 1;
    select @vmaxlen;
    
    set @sql =  coalesce(
                    concat('select lpad(n1,',@vmaxlen,',',char(39),'0',char(39),') n1,
                    lpad(n2,',@vmaxlen,',',char(39),'0',char(39),') n2
                    from t;')
                    ,'something');
    select @sql;
    prepare sqlstmt from @sql;
    execute sqlstmt;
    deallocate prepare sqlstmt;
end $$
delimiter ;
call p();

+------+------+
| n1   | n2   |
+------+------+
| 0123 | 0456 |
| 1111 | 0222 |
+------+------+
2 rows in set (0.010 sec)
```